# Doxygen recognize parameters with linebreak

Tags: fortran, doxygen, fortran90, fortran77, fixed-format

I'm trying to document my Fortran 77+90 extensions files. In general, everything works fine, except for one thing. Some of my subroutines have a little longer parameter list. Because of that, they are written with linebreak to add inline comments, as you can see below:

```
subroutine example (
                  &  a,          ! fist parameter
                  &  b,          ! second parameter
                  &  c,          ! third parameter
                  &  ...
                  &  z)          ! 26th parameter

<doing some stuff here...>

end
```

However, when I run doxygen, it doesn’t recognize these parameter, which results in an empty parameter list inside my html document. It just says:

> subroutine example ( )

Of course I can add the parameters using @param, but they don’t show up in the initial description.

Is there a hidden option/command in doxygen to get my desired output? I want something like this in my documentation:

```
subroutine example ( integer a
                     double precision b
                     ....
                     integer z )
```

This can be created when i put all my parameters inline like this:

```
subroutine example (a,b,c,...,z)

<doing some stuff here...>

end
```

Unfortunately, the requested fixed format of Fortran doesn’t let me use this. Can someone help me with that?

EDIT: This is what happens with linebreaks in the subroutine parameterlist!
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-28502940/pic.png.html

Comment: Your code doesn't look like legal Fortran. Is it fixed or free form? How do you make the line breaks? You cannot just break a line in Fortran! How do you compile it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot the '&'s !

Comment: Please also edit the code so that it is clear which column is which if it is a fixed form source.

Comment: It is just an example code! I dont know how to add a column counter though, sry! Anyway, the question is more doxygen related :-)

Comment: It is still important to see the **exact** source which the Doxygen should parse.

Comment: doxygen does nut use the comment in the subroutine definition. One can either add the documentation, as mentioned, with the @param or one can used !< behind the declaration of the variable or !> in front of it.

Comment: your code is still not valid for either fixed or free form.  Try working with something that actually compiles before messing with doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on albert's comment, you can document your subroutine for example like this:

```
  !> Get a globally defined function.
  subroutine aot_fun_global(L, fun, key)
    type(flu_state) :: L !< Handle for the Lua script.

    !> Returned handle, providing access to the function.
    type(aot_fun_type), intent(out) :: fun

    !> Name of the function to look up in the global scope of the Lua script.
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: key
```

And the [doxygen html](https://geb.sts.nt.uni-siegen.de/doxy/aotus/namespaceaot__fun__module.html#acaaee70b11f226023eb56c18818f7ae1) for it.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, in your example, the parameters of the subroutine are again listed in line and not with linebreaks and '&'. This will result in a subroutine documentation heading with all 3 parameters. if you do it like me: subroutine example (
                                                      &  a,          ! fist parameter
                                                         ....
you wont get the parameters in the documentation heading!

Comment: @AndreH The restriction to have all arguments on one line is probably a bug in Doxygen. Report it to get it fixed, that that is quite likely the only think you can do about it.

Comment: @AndreH, sorry didn't get that at first from your question. It then has to be some specifics about the form of your code, because line breaks work fine in our projects with free form, see for example https://geb.sts.nt.uni-siegen.de/doxy/treelm/namespacetem__construction__module.html#a0f43fe2ad122273b0eb9d3007c751256